# Draw line in Flex in ActionScript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, line, draw

i really don't understand what i am doing wrong:
It's simple example, but when i click on the button nothing happens..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
 xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955"minHeight="600">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        private function drawLine():void 
        {
            var myShape:Shape = new Shape();
            myShape = new Shape() ;
            myShape.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x990000, .75);
            myShape.graphics.moveTo(100, 100);

            myShape.graphics.lineTo(25, 45);
            this.addChild(myShape);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<!--<mx:Label text="Hello World"/>-->
<mx:Button label="Click" click="drawLine()" />

</s:Application>
```

Comment: Try giving myShape a height and width

Comment: Use [Line](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/primitives/Line.html); much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SpriteVisualElement` for adding simple non-flex objects.

```
<s:SpriteVisualElement width="500" height="500" id="spr"/>

spr.addChild(myShape)
```